# NSUrl from NSString returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nsstring, nsurl

I want to parse the location of my Documents Directory to `NSUrl` from `NSString` I have.

when my console NSLog(stringURL)

```
i get: "/var/mobile/Applications/2B35D06D-6E4A-40F2-833E-28463A946834/Library/Application Support/MyAppDirectory" as an output.
```

but when I do

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
```

and NSLog(url) i get (null) as an output.

WHat am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the apple documentation "An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the URL string was malformed or nil, returns nil." Your stringURL isn't a correct formed url. For reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:

What you actually want to use is: `fileURLWithPath: isDirectory:` instead.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithString:[stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isDirectory:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

Comment: Just one thing, when I log again, URL and String, i get this:

NSString URL: /var/mobile/Applications/5667FADC-F848-40CF-A309-7BFE598AE6AB/Library/Application Support/MyAppDirectory.
NSUrl URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/5667FADC-F848-40CF-A309-7BFE598AE6AB/Library/Application㤈㤋ތȀ乽啓汲唠䱒›楦敬⼺⼯慶⽲潭楢敬䄯灰楬慣楴湯⽳㘵㜶䅆䍄䘭㐸ⴸ〴䙃䄭〳ⴹ䈷䕆㤵䄸㙅䉁䰯扩慲祲䄯灰楬慣楴湯㈥匰灵潰瑲䴯䅹灰楄敲瑣牯⽹upport/MyAppDirectory/

Comment: 1st one is string and second one, with chinese letters when i log url. how did that happen ? :D

Comment: i think it is because of the whitespace between application and support, please see my edited answer

Comment: Your (invalid) suggestion of using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` causes the OP's issues with "chinese characters".  There is no need to use that method unless it's being used in an HTTP request. See his next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425439/nsurl-fileurlwithpath-returns-strange-chinese-signs/23426537#23426537

Comment: actually i made the suggestion after the op had issues with chinese characters. It was an attempt to fix this issue not my original suggestion in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithString:stringUrl];
//                  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fileURLWithPath instead (since you are passing a file path):

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringUrl];
```