# NSUrl fileURLWithPath returns strange chinese signs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I have an NSString path to my Documents folder.

```
NSString* stringURL = @"/var/mobile/Applications/5667FADC-F848-40CF-A309-
7BFE598AE6AB/Library/Application Support/MyAppDirectory";
```

When I cast it to `NSUrl` with

```
 NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringUrl];
```

and `NSLog(@"Created URL: %@",url);`, i get some strange result:

> ///var/mobile/Applications/5667FADC-F848-40CF-A309-7BFE598AE6AB/Library/Application㤈㤋ތȀ乽啓汲唠䱒›楦敬⼺⼯慶⽲潭楢敬䄯灰楬慣楴湯⽳㘵㜶䅆䍄䘭㐸ⴸ〴䙃䄭〳ⴹ䈷䕆㤵䄸㙅䉁䰯扩慲祲䄯灰楬慣楴湯㈥匰灵潰瑲䴯䅹灰楄敲瑣牯⽹upport/MyAppDirectory/

Why is this so ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How do you generate `stringUrl`?

Comment: What's that space doing in `stringURL` ("`A309- 7BFE`")?

Comment: I dont see any space.

Comment: I generate the path using: NSString *appSupportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
   appSupportDir = [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppDirectory"];

Comment: There is one in the code you posted.

Comment: There is a space, but that's not the issue. Could the problem be that you're calling `NSLog(url)` instead of `NSLog(@"%@", url)`?

Comment: @GuyKogus No, it's not the issue, but I am attempting to validate the code provided, as that often leads to clues as to the processes in operation.

Comment: I'm calling `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyAppDirectory"]);` and the output is correct...

Comment: Ok, there is a space in the question but not in the code in my computer. You were right. But it's not the issue.
As for logging, this is my code: NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSUrl URL: %@",url]);

Comment: @Guy Kogus: you get the output correct because you are logging the NSString. Try making NSURL out of it and then see if you get the right output

Comment: Why are you using `NSString withFormat` inside `NSLog()`?  You are aware that `NSLog()` performs formatting in the same way?

Comment: @Stebra I get the same result if I turn it into NSURL using `fileURLWithPath`.

Comment: `stringUrl` is different from `stringURL`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any Chinese character when I log the value.

```
NSString* stringURL = @"/var/mobile/Applications/5667FADC-F848-40CF-A309-7BFE598AE6AB/Library/Application Support/MyAppDirectory";
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringURL];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Classical mistake. Don't use NSLog (url), use NSLog (@"%@", url). The first argument to NSLog is a format string, and % characters in format strings are interpreted, not printed. For example, %s in a format string means another C-String is expected in the argument list. Since url could contain all kinds of characters, this is likely to lead to rubbish results or even crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer you accepted from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424892/nsurl-from-nsstring-returns-null); it's because the use of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will generate a *printf*-like formatting string containing `%20S` (the space between `Application Support` is converted to `%20`), which confuses `NSLog()`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithString:[stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isDirectory:YES];
NSLog(url);
```

use `NSLog("@%", url)` to avoid this error.

Comment: But this is not working. No known class method for selector"fileUrlWithString:isDirectory:'

Comment: @Stebra That code is copied from the answer *you* accepted in the other question!  I suggest you refer that the person who posted the question, as that is the reason you are here now.